# How to fetch data from string value using C#

Tags: c#-4.0

I have one string

```
str="Sales Location: 
  ROAD\nOrder Taker: DAWN RUSHIK Sales Rep: DAWN 
  RUSHIK\nPhone: (570) 650-0155 Fax: (866) 937-3391
  \nEmail: wgr@socantel.net";
```

How to fetch sales rep name?

```
Input: Sales Location: 
 ROAD\nOrder Taker: DAWN RUSHIK Sales Rep: DAWN 
 RUSHIK\nPhone: (570) 650-0155 Fax: (866) 937-3391
 \nEmail: wgr@socantel.net
```

I want below mentioned 
output: DAWN RUSHIK

Comment: There are lots of existing questions about getting part of a string using C#. Make an effort yourself, starting with at least a basic search here for a question that will get you started. This isn't a code writing service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

string pattern = @"Sales Rep: [A-Za-z]+\s[A-Za-z]+";
var result = Regex.Match(str, pattern,RegexOptions.Multiline).ToString().Split(':')[1];
MessageBox.Show(result.ToString());